# What is the procedure for testing a protocol upgrade?

Tags: protocol

How can we get example RPC data for a protocol upgrade, e.g. Babylon 2.0? How can we make transactions using the test protocol?

If we have to deploy our own private network for testing, is there documentation for how to get it done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can test Babylon using `zeronet`.
2. You can also run various network sandboxes, including ones doing full protocol transitions, see `tezos-sandbox --help` and http://tezos.gitlab.io/master/developer/flextesa.html.